# Parametric Equations of an Oblique Circular Cone

Tags: euclidean-geometry, graphing-functions, parametric

I am trying to determine the parametric equations for a specific shape of an oblique circular cone with no success. Exhaustive web searchs and many texts have not been fruitful as regards paramaterization of oblique circular cones. Since I do not know of a name for the shape of the cone needed, I will describe its properties. For reference, the orientation of the cone is with the apex at point (0, 0, 0) and opens along the +z axis to height "h" with the base diameter "b". The circular sections in the x-y plane are constrained to be such that $0 \leq y \leq b$ (that is, y values are always positve in quadrants I and II of the x-y plane) and $-\frac b2 \leq x \leq \frac b2$. The axis is the line through the points (0, 0, 0) and (0, $\frac b2$, h). The point (0, 0) of each circle in the x-y plane must be at the point z, that is, (0, 0, z). The shape of the cone then will be a right triangle in 2D when view from the x-axis with the cone height being a vertial line along the z-axis and the longest slant being from (0, 0, 0) to (0, b, h). A crude 2D text picture of the desired cone shape is below with the z-axis horizontal (+z to the left) and the y-axix vertical (+y downward). Can anyone help with the parameterization of such a shaped cone? Obviously, I have not worked out the implicit equation either although it seems it should simply be some variation of the form $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$. (The cone orientation described here is for simple reference only and ideally the parameterization should work in any orientation.) Thanks!

```
    + z ----------------------
         | | | | | | | | | | |
           | | | | | | | | | |
             | | | | | | | | |
               | | | | | | | |
                 | | | | | | |
                   | | | | | | +y
                     | | | | |
                       | | | |
                         | | |
                           | |
                             |
```

Comment: Where is the axis of the cone? Does it point in the positive z axis direction, with the apex at $(0,0,0)$? Hard to tell this location of the axis of symmetry of the cone from your description.

Comment: To Babak S. - Visualization is what I am trying to do. Just need the correct parametric form to plug into the rendering software. Part of the surface of this type cone is used in a real physical object which is fabricated by hand. I am creating a model so fabrication can be done by computer automation. First step is to create and visualize the model.

Comment: If you're creating the model in a CAD system, see if it has a "Ruled Surface" function. This is a surface defined by linear connection between two curves. But, usually, you can use a point in place of one of the curves, which will give you this cone.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have a curve $C(u)$ and a point $P$, and we want a parametric equation for the cone that has its apex at $P$ and contains the curve $C$. A suitable equation is
$$
S(u,v) = (1-v)P + vC(u)
$$
You can see that $S(u,0) = P$ and $S(u,1) = C(u)$ for all $u$. Also, if we fix $u$, then the curve $v \mapsto S(u,v)$ is a straight line passing through the points $P$ and $C(u)$.

In your case, you can use any of the circles parallel to the $xy$ plane for $C$. For example, you could use the circle in the plane $z=h$, which is
$$
C(u) = \left(0, \tfrac{b}2, h\right) + 
       \left(\tfrac{b}2 \cos u, \tfrac{b}2 \sin u, 0\right) \quad (0 \le u \le 2\pi)
$$
I checked the case $b=4$, $h=7$. Here is the Mathematica code:

```
P = {0, 0, 0};
Cu = {0, b/2, h} + {(b/2)*Cos[u], (b/2)*Sin[u], 0};
Suv = (1 - v)*P + v*Cu;
fix = {b -> 4, h -> 7};
f = Suv /. fix;
ParametricPlot3D[f, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

and here is the image it produced:

[image]

Comment: Have you ever visualized the function above? I am thinking of doing it via Maple or Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you bubba, the visualization you rendered is exactly what I was looking for. The problem I was having in the parameterization was making the center each circle in the xy-axis follow the axis of the cone. The form of the parameterization you suggest is what was needed.

Comment: @bubba: I really like the way you  parameterize the oblique cone!